# Make my computer think it's on wifi when I hotspot 3G from my phone

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, hotspot, 3g

I teach lessons over Skype, but my internet isn't very good and after a lot of attempts to improve it I've come to the conclusion that my ISP just isn't able to provide me with reliable internet. I want to tether from my phone's 3G, but the problem is that Skype is banned over mobile connections in the country I'm in, so although the internet works fine when I hotspot, Skype just doesn't work.

I've looked into VPNs but I'm worried they will cause latency, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, also they are quite expensive relative to the amount I'm earning from my lessons. I don't actually need Skype/my computer to think I'm in a different country, I just need them to think I'm on wifi in the country I'm in.

Is there any way of achieving this? Would it be possible to somehow connect my phone's 3G to the router so it came out looking like wifi? Or something I could install on my computer that would make it think I was on wifi? Or are those things impossible? I just want a couple of GB/s to be able to give good lessons!

I would be using a macbook and an iphone.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Even if you were to trick your PC into thinking it was connected to a WiFi connection, Skype would still be banned, on your 3G connection.

Comment: Depends where the limitation is: is it in the Internet service provider, in your OS, or in the application. Have you tried connecting to your phone via wifi? What happened?

Comment: Have you tried other, more standards compliant, VOIP? Maybe these are not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish what you hope with what you currently have without adding latency with a VPN. In my experience, if you were to do that over 3G, Skype would be unusable.

You have two paths out of the laptop to the internet. One is your ISP, the other is your mobile carrier. If your mobile carrier blocks Skype, the only way to get around that is to tunnel the traffic past your carrier's "walls" that block Skype. That's what the VPN would accomplish.

What the laptop "thinks" it's hooked up to is totally irrelevant. They will both seem to be regular networks. WiFi and wired makes no difference either. If Skype traffic is trying to go across your mobile carrier's network, it will get blocked. If it tried to go across your ISP, you're going to have the same problems you had before.

Answer (score 0):

I think VPN is likely to be your best bet though despite latency issues. There are quite a bundle of free VPN solutions which may still help you carry out Skype conversations.

Alternatively I would suggest you have a **3G/4G mobile dongle or modem**, Windows usually detects it as dial up connection, perhaps you beat the 3G detection trap, and you can bypass latency issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

If the ISP is blocking Skype calls on their network (you can check that by downloading skype on your phone and just trying to run it), you will not be able to establish connection when tettering.

The only good solution is to use some kind of VPN or TOR to actually bypass your ISP network.

**Latency**

Since latency is an issue for you, you can discard TOR from start. It uses 3 nodes instaed of one and inserts additional delays to make your traffic more difficult to track

As for VPN I've been using one for 3 months now for playing and online communication and it can work pretty good, without major delays.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to purchase a local internet hosting service in your country (or make use of one you or your friend might already have), some bigger service providers may also have free tier which may have sufficient bandwidth for occasional Skype. Many web hosts provides ssh access, you can set up ssh dynamic forwarding which effectively creates a SOCKS proxy server, and you can configure Skype to connect via your proxy. Alternatively, if you have a friend/company/university that runs a server hosted in your country, you may also try asking them if they want to help you by allowing you to proxy via their network.